# How can I change a data element in a $.get using values from a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How can I change a data element in a $.get using values from a JSON array?

Here's an example of the code that performs the action once:

```
          $.get(url, {
                'p': testerName,
                'magic': 'magic', //this value is constant now but may change
                'init': init1   //this is the value I want to change from a value in a JSON array
            }, function() {
                // console.log('done');

            });
```

The value I want to change is "init". For example, if "init1" is in a JSON array similar to:

```
    "initvalues":[
        {"init1":"usethisfirst"}, 
        {"init1":"usethissecond"}, 
        {"init1":"usethisthird"}
    ]
```

I want the `$.get` to run three times and stop. Of course, if there are more values in the array, it should use all of them and stop. The count of values is expected to be variable.

In the example below, if I named `var init1 = usethisfirst` it would run once.

```
        $.get(url, {
            'p': testerName,
            'magic': 'magic', //this value is constant now but may change
            'init': init1   //this is the value I want to change from a value in a JSON array
        }, function() {
            // console.log('done');

        });
```

And, I could just keep repeating the routine for every different value of "init1" but I know there must be a better way.

**Additional Info:**

The objective is to avoid hard coding repetitive `$.get` functions and use one which will run n number of times driven by the number of values in the JSON array(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to perform the get request using something like `forEach`. If all you want to do is set the `init` field from some `init1` values, you might try something like this:

```
var init_values = [
  {"init1" : "use this first"},
  {"init1" : "use this second"},
  {"init1" : "use this third"}
];

init_values.forEach(function(settings) {
  $.get(url, {
    'p' : testerName,
    'magic' : 'magic',
    'init': settings['init1']
  }, function() {
    // Do something for this particular request.
  });
});
```

However, depending upon the source of your JSON array, you might also be interested in setting the other fields automatically:

```
var init_values = [
  {
    "p" : "some value",
    "magic" : "magic",
    "init" : "use this first"
  },
  {
    "p" : "a different value",
    // No value for magic - use default.
    "init" : "use this second"
  },
  {"init" : "use this third"}  // Use defaults for 'p' and 'magic'.
];

init_values.forEach(function(settings) {
  var defaults = {
    "p" : "default p",
    "magic" : "default magic",
    "init" : "default init"
  };
  $.get(url, $.extend(defaults, settings), function() {
    // Do something for this request.
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Gonna grab a bite to eat then test this ASAP. Reading it makes perfect sense—and, thanks for going the extra mile of extending the other variables.

Comment: Boom! You made my day.